# receiving udp message is missing

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, sip

I can send a udp message to specific url and port (successfully) but I can't receive response message that I can see on Wireshark!

This is the code that I use for udp connection:

```
Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sipMessage);
String responseData = String.Empty;
IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

try
{
    using (UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(ipaddr, 5060))
    {
        udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
        udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
        Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
        responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    responseData = ex.Message;
}
```

If I don't set timeout, thread keeps working.

The response message is:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond

The result from wireshark is below:

```
+-----+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| No. |   Time    |    Source    | Destination  | Protocol | Length |                          Info                          |
+-----+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 465 | 33.378167 | 192.168.1.61 | 192.168.1.63 | SIP      |    289 | Request: MESSAGE sip:1001@192.168.1.61 |  (text/plain) |
| 469 | 33.817460 | 192.168.1.63 | 192.168.1.61 | SIP      |    254 | Status: 200 OK |                                       |
+-----+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

**addendum:** 192.168.1.61 is a computer that hosts a web page, 192.168.1.63 is a wifi dect phone

I need to send a sip message to the wifi dect (which I already achieved)

phone sends back a sip message to 192.168.1.61:5060. SIP flow is like:

> [Random Port] -- Message --> [5060]
>
> [5060] <-- 200 OK -- [5060]

so, pc connect to dect as a udp client and sends message, dect sends back 200 OK sip message to pc's 5060 port. I have problem on receiving 200 OK message!

**NEWS:** When I stop pbx server's services, I can get the result (200 OK); otherwise, I'm not able to receive any sip message...

Answer (score 0):

The UDP protocol does not work like that. It's one-way only. It does not verify the listening party is ready to receive, not does it give any response about succesful delivery of the data.

If you want feedback, try using TCP.

Comment: What is "udpClient.Receive"?

Comment: For receiving data from the sender. if you have both server and client under control, you can/must write the response yourself.

Comment: As you can see on wireshark logs, there is a response message from udp.

Comment: I recommend you setup a second client, so you have one for sending and one for listening.

Comment: Already tried and same result

`UdpClient udpSender = new UdpClient();
                UdpClient udpReceiver = new UdpClient();
                udpReceiver.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
                udpSender.Connect(ipaddr, 5060);
                udpReceiver.Client.Bind(RemoteIpEndPoint);
                udpSender.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
                Byte[] receiveBytes = udpReceiver.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

                responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

                udpSender.Close();
                udpReceiver.Close();`

Answer (score 0):

When you create your UDP Socket like this `new UdpClient(ipaddr, 5060)` you bind it to any available local port, and connect it to remote server with IP `ipaddr` and port `5060`. So when you send something over this socket, it reaches the server.

However, this socket will not see SIP replies from the server. Server is going to send SIP reply message to 5060 (or 5061 for encrypted SIP). But you are not listening on this part (in fact, nobody is, so kernel just drops this datagram). To properly receive those messages, you need to bind your local udp socket to SIP port as well.

Comment: How can I bind udpClient to sip port?
I tried this
`udpClient.Client.Bind(RemoteIpEndPoint);`
but this give me an error
`An invalid argument was supplied`

Comment: You can't bind to remote ip. You need to bind to local ip.

Comment: Now I get `Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted` Could you send an example code or link?

Comment: That means you are trying to bind two of them to the same address. You need to really get to books and study the usage of UdpClient.